# Does Microsoft SQL Server provides bitemporal historization?

Tags: sql-server

I want to use bitemporal historization in Microsoft SQL Server as in know it from e.g. DB2 (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=tables-creating-bitemporal).
There we can create a table via

```
CREATE TABLE policy_info
(policy_id CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
coverage INT NOT NULL,
bus_start DATE NOT NULL,
bus_end DATE NOT NULL,
sys_start TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW BEGIN,
sys_end TIMESTAMP(12) NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
create_id TIMESTAMP(12) GENERATED ALWAYS AS TRANSACTION START ID,
PERIOD BUSINESS_TIME(bus_start, bus_end),
PERIOD SYSTEM_TIME(sys_start, sys_end));
```

where

- SYSTEM_TIME (works in MSQL_Server) refers to technical information in database changes and logs everything in a history-table and
- BUSINESS_TIME (does it exist in MSQL server?) refers to the business-reated validity of data (e.g. the lastname of Employee with Employee_ID = 4711 was "Schmidt" from 3.6.21 until 5.7.21 and "Müller" from 6.7.21 until 23.1.22).

Does Microsoft SQL-Server provide a feature analogue to the BUSINESS_TIME in DB2?

Comment: SQL Server only supports system-versioned temporal tables where the time of row validity is maintained automatically based on the time the changes were made to the database. It doesn't support application defined time validity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comment: There is no bitemporal historization for SQL-Server.